# Except statement with a while statement

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, try-except

i got this situation:

```
datelist = pd.date_range(dateFrom, dateTo, dateperiods)
while i < len(datelist):
    Date=datelist[i].floor('D')
    print(f'{Date} STARTED')
    if i!=0:
       Date2=datelist[i-1].floor('D')
    else: 
       Date2=Date
    i = i + 1
    try:
        **COMPLEX AND LONG CODE THAT USE DATE AS A PARM**
    except Exception as inst:
        print(inst)
        print(f'--------elaboration for {Date} failed. stated elaboration 
 for next date--------')
        if i < len(datelist):
            Date=datelist[i].floor('D')
            print(f'--{Date} STARTED')
            globalsdatelist.append(Date)
            Date2=datelist[i-1].floor('D')
            i = i + 1
        else:
            print('request failed')
            break
        **COMPLEX AND LONG CODE THAT USE DATE AS A PARM**
```

what i want is to continue the except while i<len(datelist) not just the first time an error occurred.
there is an easy way to do it?
thank you so much

Comment: Put the try/except inside the loop and in the except branch `continue`. PS: your indentation looks wrong, can you make sure the code is indented as you have it running?

Comment: no, this would simple create multiple while loops. Ideal way is to put the loop outside and the try except inside the loop and just intercept the exception and pass through if the condition is not right.

Comment: hello @GPhilo, i corrected a bit the indentation. sorry for the trouble, this code is my life for two weeks and i see it when i close my eyes, my mind just "autocorrected" the indentation that is not clear, sorry again.

Comment: hello @AnirudhPanchangam, i didn't understand what you told me to try. can i ask to try to say it again? i edited to have a clearer indentation, is this could help

Comment: Sure, as you can see from the answer below, you will need to place the while loop on the outside of the try except, so you will be iterating  the datelist in only one while group, and any exceptions that occur in the while loop are caught in the except block but since there is no break , it will never come out of the while loop until while loop condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
datelist = pd.date_range(dateFrom, dateTo, dateperiods)
while i < len(datelist):
  try:
    **COMPLEX AND LONG CODE THAT USE DATE AS A PARM**
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    #handle exception case appropriately
```